# How to get the localforage value without using promise in ionic1

Tags: javascript, localforage

I am having a local forage which stores the user details.I need to get these details without using localforage.getItem() which uses a promise value.
Even i have tried using $scope.localforagekey but when i close the app and open again the value gets cleared.
Can anyone tell me how to get the value from local forage without using promise.

Answer (score 0):

Localforage is async by design, since indexeddb & websql only provide async methods for setting and retrieving data.
One thing you could do to make your code more sync-like is to use `await`, even though that is almost equivalent to moving all your code inside a `.then`.
An other option would be to retrieve/resolve the required value in the ionic router, so that the value is already available (injected) to the controller by the time it loads.